# How to push a data exactly to required index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to `push` a data at the exact position to an `array` but the result i am getting is wrong...

any one show me the correct way to do this?

my code :

```
var ar = ['one','two','three'];

ar[5] = 'five';

ar.join();

console.log(ar); //result ["one", "two", "three", 5: "five"]
```

the result i am looking is :

```
["one", "two", "three", "", "", "five"]
```

**Update**
[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/1e3kbovj/)

Comment: This must be ur brower fault.Else ur code is working for me .Check it with chrome

Comment: What are you expecting? Remember that arrays are zero-indexed...

Comment: Note: `ar.join()` does nothing useful in your above code. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @all please can you look in to this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/1e3kbovj/

Comment: It's an array object, not a regular object. Indexing works differently. Array fills out the missing indexes. Also ar.join() does nothing.

Comment: Perhaps you actually want to add something to the end of the array? If so, there's `ar.push('five')` which will result in the same as what you want with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ar.join()` doesn't change `ar`.  This should accomplish what you're looking for, as long as you don't have pipes (|) in your data:

```js
console.clear();
var ar = ['one','two','three'];

ar[5] = 'five';

console.log(ar);  //["one", "two", "three", 5: "five"]

ar= ar.join('|').split('|');

console.log(ar);  //["one", "two", "three", "", "", "five"]
```

Comment: I am updating the `array` by `return`, but not works... go here http://jsfiddle.net/1e3kbovj/1/ (requires for my project)

Comment: `update()` by itself doesn't change `ar`.  So you should assign its output to `ar` like this:  `ar= update();`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct. What you have done is equivalent to:

```
a = ["one", "two", "three", undefined, undefined, "five"]
```

The way that browser is displaying it is different from Chrome's console, which shows:

```
["one", "two", "three", undefined × 2, "five"]
```

If you want empty strings in the 'holes' you must put them there yourself, for example:

```
var a = ["one", "two", "three"];
a[3] = a[4] = "";
a[5] = "five";
```

---

<sub>*And yes, please note that `"one"` is at index 0, not index 1.*</sub>

Comment: The 'output' is just an attempt at making a human-readable version of the data structure. You have linked to a JSFiddle using different code from your question. If you have a new question, please post it as a new question.